# Server Action: Loop through each record of model

Tags: for-loop, server, action, odoo-10

I have a server action to update product costs when selected in tree view:

```py
bom_obj = env["mrp.bom"] 
for product in object.browse(context.get('active_ids')):
    price = 0 
    bom = bom_obj._bom_find(product=product) 
    if bom:
        price = product._calc_price(bom)
        product.write({'standard_price':price})
```

But This unfortunately only selects records visible in tree view, not ALL the records in product.product

I tried:

```py
bom_obj = env["mrp.bom"] 
product_obj = env["product.product"]
product_ids = product_obj.search(cr, uid, [])
   for product in product_ids:
      price = 0 
      bom = bom_obj._bom_find(product=product) 
      if bom:
          price = product._calc_price(bom)
          product.write({'standard_price':price})
```

Could you please tell me how to loop through each record of product.product.

OR

instead, tell me how I would go about update price of record selected in m2o field.

I know how to trigger the code in server action, I just need to know how to get record from m2o field. I will use this when product_id is changed in Sale Order Line, to update the price as it is selected.

Thanks